# How to composite an animation?

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor, glare

How to composite an animation?

I am trying to add some effects like fo example glare, but I would like to animate it and be able to see the process like in After Effects. Can I use compositor after the frames are rendered and add to video editing? If yes - how?

Comment: Yes you need to use the Compositor for effects like glare, but maybe give some details?

Comment: Do you mean running the compositor on the sequencer output? Not sure if this is possible directly, but you can render out from the sequencer, and then load the result into the compositor by itself as a clip input.

Comment: I think this video explains what I am trying to do, but instead of inverting, I would like to use glare or other effects in video editing like that. This is a plugin, but is there a way to do it without it?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYCDC3O2hxs

Comment: I don't think so, otherwise there wouldn't be a plugin

Comment: Yup, compositing from the video editor is impossible as of today. But, if you are only adding effects, why do you want to use the VSE in the first place? Just put your rendered image sequence in the compositor. Be sure to have it rendered into EXR or anything with a high bit depth.

Comment: @L0Lock But can you see a movie or image sequence in real time in the Compositor? It doesn't look like

Comment: Blender doesn't have top-notch performance no matter how you put it so no, not "real time" as in "smooth playback", but you do get to see your sequence as is with whatever effects you want to use (and being able to send the VSE to the compositor would still have the same performance issue, if not worse): https://i.imgur.com/b2Sn7cz.jpeg

Comment: I need to see it in a compositor because if I animate glare It's not so easy to predict what it's going to look like on an animation. And where it comes to the detail - that is quite important. Thank you everyone for your answers!